# Why didn't Dudley answer Bud White's question here?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

At the restaurant scene in *L.A Confidential* (1997), Dudley speaks to the suspended cop Bud White and reveals a
police badge and gun in front of him:

> Dudley: They're yours. Go ahead, take them.

Immediately, Bud White grabs the police badge and gun in front of him:

> Bud White: **There's no goddamn bill on me?**
>
> Dudley: Four witnesses recanted their testimony.

Here Dudley didn't directly answer Bud White's question about a bill. Instead, he talked
about four witnesses changing their statements.

Why didn't Dudley answer Bud White's question here?

Comment: I think that Dudley answered the question best that he could.  He's completely corrupt and that's all that he could say.  I personally think that Dudley killed Exley's father and is the real Rollo Tomasi.   https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38875/did-captain-dudley-smith-kill-lieutenant-edmund-exleys-father

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He *did* answer, obliquely.

If four witnesses retracted their statements, there's not enough to push for a charge.